# reference request / study plan - to build a solid foundation in mathematics for research in ML and optimisation

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, optimization, self-learning, machine-learning

reference request / study plan - to build a solid foundation in mathematics for research in ML and optimisation

Comment: If you wanna do research in ML, before learning any optimization, you need to learn A LOT of Statistics. That should actually be your first priority. Note that another name for Machine Learning is Statistical Learning.

Comment: It looks more like a chart of every branch of mathematics, instead of a realistic study plan.

Comment: I agree with @高田航. Your study plan is completely unrealistic. You should look at the suggested mathematics background for graduate study in ML, which should be easy to determine because I would imagine most every such program has at least some of this information on their web pages, and after looking at this for a few dozen of the better known ML programs, you should get a pretty good sense of what is needed. Your study plan would be difficult to accomplish in an average lifetime.

Comment: Learn the basics of statistics, linear algebra and analysis well. As for the rest, I find it useful to first isolate the precise problem I want to tackle, and then identify the topics I need to solve that specific problem backwards. Sure, get an idea of what everything you have sketched does, but tackling all those topics in even a medium amount of detail is only possible if you are a superhuman.

Comment: @高田航: this is incorrect, as there are many branches and topics of mathematics not listed in the diagram.

Comment: Do not deface your post.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, delete group theory and all successor nodes.  You can also probably safely get rid of algebraic and differential topology, unless you are 100% sure that you want to work on manifold learning or topological data analysis, which I wouldn't necessarily recommend if you're just starting out.

But I'm not going to go through it node by node, because the diagram is fundamentally broken for a simple reason: there is no actual machine learning anywhere in it.  If you spent 4+ years learning all of that, at what point would you have learned about logistic regression, or principal component analysis, or neural networks?  You can understand all of those things with only linear algebra, multivariable calculus, and probability theory.  Most of the other topics in the diagram are used at best for niche algorithms which address niche use cases.

Here's an alternative plan:
1. Get a copy of Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Bishop (PDF available for free online) and start reading the first 5 chapters.
2. If you get to a point where it's all gibberish, fill in the relevant technical background - probably that will be either probability theory, linear algebra, or multivariable calculus.
3. Try to read Part II of Goodfellow's deep learning book (available free online).
4. Now go find a paper that you want to read and work through it, using Goodfellow as a reference.

Odds are you'll have the technical background to work on a research problem by this point.  You could conceivably need some real analysis / measure theory depending on what you want to do, but other than that you should just focus on picking up what you need to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have read most part of Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning, the book teaches common techniques in machine learning and some mathematical background of these techniques. But it does not go in-depth about the mathematical framework used to derive these methods, which is needed if one wants to invent new methods, instead of just learning how to use existing methods. For Groups, I'm currently working on a project in Number Theoretic Transform, which does require a little knowledge of Groups and Rings.

Comment: Machine learning is not a branch of mathematics, and for the most part it was not invented by mathematicians.  Progress in the field is generally made by beating benchmarks in publicly available datasets, either in terms of accuracy or algorithmic performance, not by proving theorems.  (Indeed, there are at the moment very few theorems about the best performing algorithms for many machine learning tasks.)  If you already have a specific problem in mind that is heavy on theory then by all means learn whatever you need, but your study plan is highly unfocused and mostly irrelevant.

Comment: Also, the number-theoretic transform is really a topic in numerical analysis, not ML / optimization - there are lots of applications of numerical analysis to ML, but this isn't really a core part of the subject.  Most of the algebraic topics in your plan - rings, fields, representation theory, category theory, etc. are *massive* overkill for this, and will have no applications (except maybe to niche problems like gauge equivariant neural networks).  Again, this is all a huge waste of your time in comparison to, say, working directly with data.